# Xcode trigger navigationBar-Back-Button-Action

Tags: xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

i have a navigationcontroller with some viewcontrollers and i need to know
how i can trigger the back-button-action on the navigationBar of each viewcontroller.

i have an allert-view and when user presses ok on this alert-view i want the
navigationcontroller to get one step back so i need to trigger the back-button
which appears on each navigationbar on the left side.

Does somebody knows how this works :)

Because if it doenst works i have to implement a navigationcontroller under each viewcontroller to make

```
[self dismissViewController animated:YES completion:nil]
```

and i dont want to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pop the front most view controller from the stack.

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

You could also use

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:someViewController animated:YES];
```

if you wanted to go directly back to someViewController.